# Search an ArrayList for values in another ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have two different `ArrayList` instances, one of type `Container` and one of type `String`. The first is a list of "banned goods" (strings) for a country, and the other is a list of containers on a ship. The ship travels through the country, and the containers are searched for the banned goods. If the container `contains` the banned goods, that container should be removed/deleted.

```
public Customs(String country)
{
    countryName = country;
    bannedGoods = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public Ship(String n, double weight)
{
    emptyWeight = totalWeight = weight;
    name = n;
    containers = new ArrayList<Container>();
}
```

I already have a method in the Ship class that removes the container:

```
public void removeContainer(int i) 
{
    if(i >= 0 && i < containers.size()) {
        Container r = containers.remove(i);
        totalWeight = totalWeight - r.getWeight();
    }       
}
```

I am trying to create an method to `inspect` the ship for the containers. I want to use two for-loops for each of the arrays, but I can't seem to get it right! Can someone help me use the two loops to search the arrays? Additionally, I think that I will need to use an iterator (the `remove` function, specifically) in the loop, but that is also confusing for me. Should the iterator `remove` method replace the method I already wrote in class ship? Here is what I have:

```
public void inspect(Ship ship) 
{
    for (String good : bannedGoods) {
        for (String con : containers) {
            if (con.contains(good) {
                container.remove();
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is my attempt at the iterator:

```
for(String good : bannedGoods) {
    Iterator<String> it = ship.containers.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext())
            if (ship.contains(good))
                it.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need 2 for loops. You should iterate over banned goods & simply remove it from the containers.

Also, Assuming that `containers` list is of type `string` as this is mentioned in your fist line : `I have two different arrayLists of the same type String`

```
public void inspect(Ship ship, ArrayList<String> bannedGoods){
    if (ship == null || bannedGoods == null || bannedGoods.isEmpty())
        return;
    for(String good : bannedGoods){
        ship.containers.remove(good);
    }
}
```

If, `Containers` is of type `Container` and it contains a list of containers`(Arraylist of string)` which is accessible via the method `get_containers()`, the following would work:

```
public void inspect(Ship ship, ArrayList<String> bannedGoods){
    if (ship == null || bannedGoods == null || bannedGoods.isEmpty())
        return;
    for(String good : bannedGoods){
        for(Container container : ship.containers){
            container.get_containers().remove(good);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `containers` is a list of `Container` objects, not strings. Also `inspect` is presumably an instance method of `Customs`, so it has direct access to the `bannedGoods` list.

Comment: the OP has written this as the first line : `I have two different arrayLists of the same type String`

Comment: It would appear that the second list is within the `Container`. See the ship constructor, `containers = new ArrayList<Container>();`.

Comment: Yes, sorry! One array is of type String and the other is of type Container. Sorry for the mistake! I've edited my post.

Comment: @SamStan Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can stick to the methods you are using at the moment. But keep in mind that you either need to use the iterator's remove method or not use iterators. So to use your remove method, either implement `Iterable` or simply use indexes instead of iterators:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bannedGoods.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < containers.size();) // NOTE: no j++ here
    {
        Container c = containers.get(j);
        if (c.contains(bannedGoods.get(i))
            c.removeContainer(j);
        else
            j++; // only if you don't remove the container increment
                 // j - when removing the next element gets current
                 // index
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're actually pretty close, and you've done a good job of focusing on object-oriented programming principles while designing your classes. I think the things you need to focus on now are just being more careful with your types. Below are some suggested modifications to your classes (`Container` isn't shown, but I'm assuming it has a `public boolean contains (String s)` method that checks whether the container has a certain good `s` inside.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Ship implements Iterable<Container> {
    private double emptyWeight, totalWeight, weight;
    private String name;
    private List<Container> containers = new ArrayList<Container>();

    public Ship(String n, double weight) {
        emptyWeight = totalWeight = weight;
        name = n;
    }

    private void removeContainer(int i) {
        if (i >= 0 && i < containers.size()) {
            Container r = containers.remove(i);
            totalWeight = totalWeight - r.getWeight();
        }       
    }

    public Iterator<Container> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<Container> {
            private index = 0;
            private Container previous = null;

            public boolean hasNext() {
                return index < containers.size();
            }

            public Container next() {
                if (!hasNext()) {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();
                }
                previous = containers.get(index++);

                return previous;
            }

            public void remove() {
                if (previous == null) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException();
                }

                removeContainer(containers.indexOf(previous));

                previous = null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I suggest keeping `removeContainer` within your `Ship` class since it's responsible for keeping track of how its weight changes when a container is removed. For the same reason, don't allow external classes to directly access its `containers` list. That way you can prevent other code from adding or removing values from that list without updating the `weight` correctly. I'd suggest making the `containers` list private, and expose an `Iterator` to allow users of the class to interact with the containers.

Within your `Customs` class, you'd use the `Iterator`'s `remove` method to remove offending `Container` instances:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Customs {
    private String countryName;
    private List<String> bannedGoods = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Customs(String country) {
        countryName = country;
    }

    public void inspect(Ship ship) {
        for (String good : bannedGoods) {
            for (Iterator<Container> it = ship.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                Container container = it.next();

                if (container.contains(good) {
                    it.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```